# Is there a way to pass `ngFor` item as a parameter to a function

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am getting shuffled object value from backend. to fix that, I want to retrive the exact value by title. but how to pass from different `ngFor` loop in to others/

html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hfsTableSchema">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of headers; let i = index"  >{{header.title}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let object of rows">
        <td *ngFor="let item of object|keyvalue">{{setValue(object, header)}}</td>//how?
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

because I could not able to use the `item.value` directly. the values are not correct as per header label.

I want to do this;

```
setValue(object, header){
  return object[header.tite]
}
```

so it will match the correct value. any one help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your header is some like

```
header=[{title:'One',column:'one'},{title:'Two',column:'two'},..]
```

iterate again over headers for the td

```
<tr *ngFor="let object of rows">
    <td *ngFor="let header of headers">{{object[header.column]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a value of the `*ngFor` outside of its template. It has to be a child to access the value.

This is intentional because we want the value to be scoped and not leaked into other part of the HTML.

That's why we can do this following without any errors:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of products">{{item}}</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of employers">{{item}}</div>

<!-- item value is scoped, so it won't interfere with one another-->
```

#### What you can do is to use the `headers` in the `td` loop:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="hfsTableSchema">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of headers; let i = index">{{header.title}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let object of rows">
        <td *ngFor="let header of headers">{{object[header.title]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```